# OrchardCMS - Can't find correct alternative to render widget

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to add a image carousel to my CMS site and in the process learn about [Alternatives](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates).

I've go the following content types

- BannerImage (TextField and a MediaPicker field)
- ImageGallery (Container)

I've created a bunch of images, added them as 'Containables' to a new ImageGallery and 
I then create a widget, put it in BeforeContent and it renders as an ugly list (default rendering)

I have been able to customize the images by using the alternative *Content-BannerImage.Summary.cshtml*, sweet.. so far so good.

BUT I'm not able to customize the rendering of the ImageGallery at all. The alternative
*Content-ImageGallery.Summary.cshtml* or *.Detail* or even *Widget-Container.cshtml* do not work at all.

The alternative that IS being used is *Widget.Wrapper.cshtml* which came with the theme I'm using. I'm not able to find the correct alternative so I can prevent the ImageGallery from rendering it's name/title (which it does by default from the *Widget.Wrapper.cshtml* alternative.

Any help is greatly appreciated and before it's mentioned... I've read http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes which is a great doco, but I'm too dumb to figure it out :)

Ta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create an alternate (not alternative) for a widget, you first have to activate the **Widget Alternates** module.

Once you have done so, create your widget, and activate the **Shape Tracing** module. Go to the page where the widget appears, click on the shape tracing button on the bottom right corner to show the shape tracing and select your widget.
You should now see a list of possible alternates for your widget. Select one and click the link to create it. Now you just have to edit it to your taste.

Comment: Thanks Falanwe, will get back soon with the results

Comment: Hi Falanwe, this is a brilliant tool I had no idea how to use - thanks heaps. This will definately help me figure out how things fit together in the future.

Comment: What I'm still a little confused about, is that the Alternate makes no reference to the content type (ImageGallery), it is only a ContainerWidget even though I haven't defined it as such. The part is buried down the zone tree under widget->list->content.

thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how the image gallery module you're using is working, the shape that you need to override to render the list of images. It is probably the List shape that you need to change. This article should give you a good starting point: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/27/taking-over-list-rendering-in-orchard.aspx

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, I've only had a chance to read through the post but not test the code yet but I think that might fix it. Will report back soon.

Comment: Hi Bertrand, after looking at the shapes module it looks like the Widget shape is being used, to render the ImageGallery content type (I still can't find where in the model it makes reference to the containable image gallery content type.

Also thanks for the blogs, they're a great resource

Comment: Right, so the widget shape will get rendered, which just does Display(Model.Content), which renders a Content shape, which renders local zones, where your part shapes get placed then rendered. One of those part shapes will likely render a list shape, or something similar. That's what you need to look for.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, makes sense now.